# Tagging foreign text using isascii in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to create a very simple non-English word identification script which replaces every word in a text with a `<FOREIGN>` tag if that word contains any specific non-English character. For this I used the `.isascii()` method.

I have the following sample string:

```
s = "abc def déf äëü المزيد 한글  - 1 2 3 4 5"
```

And the following is the expected output:

```
s_exp = "abc def <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN> - 1 2 3 4 5"
```

My current working implementation is:

```
import re
for word in s.split():
    if not word.isascii():
        s = re.sub(word, "<FOREIGN>", s)
```

While this works perfectly for small amount of data, I am worried about its performance on 100,000s of rows of textual data organized in a pandas dataframe. I was wondering if there is any solution that might be better performing than this for loop. At the moment, I am using
`df['Text'].apply(lambda x: replace_nonenglish(x))` where `replace_nonenglish` is:

```
def replace_nonenglish(s):
    for word in s.split():
        if not word.isascii():
            s = re.sub(word, "<FOREIGN>", s)
    return s
```

### Note:

I am fully aware that this will provide a bunch of false negatives, i.e. non-English words not tagged as `<FOREIGN>` such as the French "bien" or the German "gut" but that is acceptable for now.

Comment: This question is too broad and loosely defined for Stack Overflow. Like to start, have you actually tried your code on your big dataframe, and was it in fact too slow? For improving working code, you can ask on [codereview.se] instead. BTW, you might want to read [their How to Ask page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Oops, actually [Code Review might not be the best place for this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355634/4518341). Instead, please be more specific: try your code on a chunk of your big dataset and see if it's performant enough. If it isn't, specify how exactly, and provide some example data so we can test it ourselves.

Comment: FWIW, your code doesn't need regex, though if it did, it should use `re.escape(word)`. Instead of `re.sub()`, you could just use `str.replace()`. Although, doing multiple replacements might be wasteful either way, and the better solution might be to filter individual words then rejoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

```py
import re
s = "abc def déf äëü المزيد 한글  - 1 2 3 4 5"
print( re.sub(r"\b[a-zA-Z]*[^\W\d_a-zA-Z][^\W\d_]*\b", "<FOREIGN>", s) )
# => abc def <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN> <FOREIGN>  - 1 2 3 4 5
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sj3pOE) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2SXrc1/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary (it is Unicode aware in Python by default)
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters
- `[^\W\d_a-zA-Z]` - any Unicode letter but an ASCII letter
- `[^\W\d_]*` - zero or more Unicode letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

With the PyPi regex library (install with `pip install regex` in your terminal/console window) it would look a bit cleaner:

```py
import regex
s = "abc def déf äëü المزيد 한글  - 1 2 3 4 5"
print( regex.sub(r"\b[a-zA-Z]*[^\P{L}a-zA-Z]\p{L}*\b", "<FOREIGN>", s) )
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqtYwVZBKTEpWSElNU0h5fDKNIXDSw6vPrxH4cbymy03W29sutl1Y73C26lzXu1oUFDQVTBUMFIwVjBRMFXiKijKzCvRgJijV1yapFGkFJMUnahb5agbFasVHRcTUO1TC@XGFADZWjFJSjoKSjZu/kGunu5@dkBOsaaC5v//AA). Here, `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter and `\P{L}` matches any char other than a Unicode letter.